# Is there a way I can turn off the ACS ACR122U NFC Reader while still connected to a USB port?

Tags: electrical

I have a use case where I need to turn off the ACS ACR122U completely and put it back on while still connected to the USB port. I cannot disconnect the reader from the PC. Disabling the port still leaves the reader lights on. I need it fully off.

Is there anything I can attach to this reader to turn it on and off or maybe with APDU commands?

Comment: start by reading the data sheet